# Adding and Removing class on clicks (in wordpress loop)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

So I have a wordpress loop to show certain posts. Each posts has a modal that I'll show the  in and each modal is triggered by the .modal-trigger class. However, because there are more than one posts I want to prevent the user from opening more than one modal at a time and this is why I want to remove the .modal-trigger class once it is clicked. I will then addClass the .modal-trigger once the .fa-close is clicked

my main objective is to remove the `.modal-trigger` class once it is clicked and add this class once the `.fa-close` class is clicked

```
<section class="meet-the-team">
    <div class="inner">
            <?php
                $team = new wp_query (array(
                    'post_type' => 'team',
                    'orderby'   => 'date',
                    'order'        =>   'ASC'
                ));
                if($team->have_posts()):
                    while($team->have_posts()):
                        $team->the_post();
            ?>
            <div class="team-section">
          <p class="team-header"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
          <p class="team-details"><?php the_field('person_job_title'); ?></p>

        <button class="button modal-trigger ">Read More</button>

                    <!-- MODAL SECTION FOR READ MORE POSTS -->
                    <div class="my-Modal">
                     <i class="fa fa-close"></i>
                     <?php the_title(); ?>
                     <p><?php the_field('person_job_title'); ?></p>
                     <?php the_content(); ?>
                    </div>
                <!-- ENDING OF MODAL SECTION -->
      </div>
             <?php
                endwhile;
                else: "no posts available" ;
                endif;
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.modal-trigger').click(function(){
        var post_content = $(this).parent('.team-section').find('.my-Modal').fadeIn().css('transform' , 'translate(0px , 15%)' );
        $('.button .modal-trigger').removeClass('modal-trigger');
    });
    $('.fa-close').click(function(){
        $('.my-Modal').fadeOut().css('transform' ,  'translate(0px , 5%)');
        $('.button .modal-trigger').addClass('modal-trigger');
    });
});
```

thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work because your opening click removes the class you use to 'close' as well. Essentially, the following element you try to select doesn't exist anymore:

`$('.button .modal-trigger').addClass('modal-trigger');`

I'd go with a global variable that blocks all clicks when active, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var hasActiveModal = false;

    $('.modal-trigger').click(function(){
        if(!hasActiveModal) {
            hasActiveModal = true;
            var post_content = $(this).parent('.team-section').find('.my-Modal').fadeIn().css('transform' , 'translate(0px , 15%)' );
            return;
        }
    });
    $('.fa-close').click(function(){
        if(hasActiveModal) {
            hasActiveModal = false;
            $('.my-Modal').fadeOut().css('transform', 'translate(0px , 5%)');
            return;
        }
    });
});
```

This way you keep track of an active modal, and only allow modals to be opened when there's no open modal, and close them when there's a modal open.